# Is BufferedWriter.append in Java thread safe?

Tags: java, processbuilder

So I have a file that multiple threads try to write to simultaneously.

I used Buffered Writer to write to the file. Now, my question is if use append to append thread's content to the file, will it be thread safe?

Comment: Are they all using the same writer?

Comment: Yes.. The writer is an member of a object. That object is shared with all the threads.

Comment: Yes, in short, the writes are synchronised, internally, on a common `lock` - so if all the threads are using the same instance of the writer, then the individual writes will be synchronised. You can investigate it yourself by digging through the code a little

Comment: @MadProgrammer but that isn't a documented property, so it would be inadvisable to rely on it.

Comment: @AndyTurner It could be an oversight, given all the other awesome documentation errors that exist :/

Comment: @AndyTurner the superclass Writer's javadoc language indicates the subclasses need to synchronize on the object `lock` to protect their critical sessions. Could have been more explicit, but it's there

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt true, but it doesn't define what the critical sections are.

Comment: @AndyTurner I guess it comes down to the definition of "critical sections". Perhaps raise a change request to have the documentation more clearly defined :/

Comment: Yes granted not very explicit. But "critical section" is a commonly understood term. Wikipedia states "concurrent accesses to shared resources can lead to unexpected or erroneous behavior, so parts of the program where the shared resource is accessed are protected. This protected section is the critical section or critical region.", that's also my understanding of a critical section

Answer (score 2):

When you inspect the implementation, you can see that there is a lock object and the methods such as `write` or `flush` are synchronizing with a common object `lock`.

```
synchronized (lock) {
  ... here is the body of the method, enclosed in the sync block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with the question "is it thread safe" is that the answer depends upon what you mean by thread safety.

A class can be thread safe, in the sense that its own invariants cannot be broken by its use by multiple threads simultaneously; but you can still use that class in a non-threadsafe way.

For example:

```
void write(int a, String blah) {
  writer.write(a);
  writer.write(blah);
}
```

These two writes are not performed atomically, so there is a possibility that the writes from two threads interleave.

If you are in any doubt about thread safety, manage it yourself.

Comment: I think it's fairly obvious from my question, that I am not asking about chaining together multiple appends or asking about a situation where I deliberately try to break the thread safety of the append method(if it was thread safe). I have described my use case in the question.