# Is file thread-safe in java/kotlin

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, thread-safety

I have a File instance in Kotlin which is local. I just want to know whether multiple threads/co-routines can access this file instance at the same time and write to it. There are some lines missing from the output file, and that may be the reason.

As the file instance is local, each thread/co-routine it should have it's own instance, and there should not be such a problem IMO.

```
private val noOfThreads = newFixedThreadPoolContext(nThreads = 3, name = "coRoutineThreads")
val nameOfFile = "test.csv"
fun coRoutineFunction(){
    runBlocking{
        for(i in 1..100)
        {
            async(noOfThreads){
               writeToFile(nameOfFile)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun writeToFile(nameOfFile){
    val file = File(fileName)
    //write to file using bufferedWriter and CSVPrinter
}
```

The original writeToFile, will get the fileName and data to be added to the file. If file does not exist, it will create new file, otherwise it will append.

```
internal fun writeToFile(fileName: String, recordList: List<Map<String, String>>) {
try {
    val file = File(fileName)
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile()
        val writer = FileWriter(file)
        val bufferedWriter = BufferedWriter(writer)
        writeCSVRecordWithHeader(bufferedWriter, recordList)
        bufferedWriter.close()
    } else {
        val writer = FileWriter(file, true)
        val bufferedWriter = BufferedWriter(writer)
        concCSVRecord(bufferedWriter, recordList)
        bufferedWriter.close()
    }
} catch (exception: Exception) {
    logger.error("Exception at writeRecordsToFile while creating file: ${ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception)}")
    throw exception
}
```

Comment: Yes, the `file`, any `File` is thread-safe because it does not contain any logic or state. But what do you expect n threads writing to the same physical file to do? That will break in some way.

Comment: The file may be huge, and a single thread writing to the file takes a lot of time. So, I have n threads writing to the same file. Also, can you explain the "it does not have any state"? What I understood was say an int variable can have a state, say 5, but a file can also have a state rt? Say 5 lines of text

Comment: *How* are you planning on writing to a single file from multiple process? Why do you think multiple threads will make it any faster, is CPU your bottleneck, not IO? You should then be using e.g. a `RandomAccessFile` instead. I do not think a `BufferedWriter` can write at given offsets.

Comment: A file has contents and you could call that state, but a `File` object has no state, it does not know what the physical file contains.

Comment: `File` doesn't represent the contents of the file.  It's just a reference to a place in the filesystem, not really any different than a `String`.

Comment: The original code doesn't have a for loop like in the question. Rather it has a list of objects, which is passed to another function, which converts it to a list of strings and then if file does not exist it creates one otherwise it appends to the file.

Comment: I'm not sure if the state of the File object reflects its locking characteristics or multi-thread access.  Same as databases.  Might want to be careful.  https://www.baeldung.com/java-lock-files

Comment: Hmm, there has to be a reason some lines are missing in the file. I am guessing it's because of multi-thread access.

Comment: I found something similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289631/is-bufferedwriter-append-in-java-thread-safe . It says that if the writer object is common for all threads then the writes will be synchronized.

Comment: NB You don't need all this `file.exists()`/`file.createNewFile()` business. Just use the second block where you open the file in append mode. That will create it if necessary, without the timing-window problems and redundancy of your code.